# how to fix a computer screen that was dropped?

Tags: technology

How can I fix a computer screen That I dropped? I tried to glue the pieces together and well it didn't work.

Comment: No life hack.  You need to replace the screen.

Comment: There's no life hack for this. The glass isn't the issue, the electronics underneath are broken and are too small to fix by hand.

Answer (score 2):

If you break a glass window, what is your best option to repair it?

As much as I wish there was an easy way to fix a cracked computer or iPhone screen, as of right now there is no easy way for an average Joe to do this.  Usually, the best option is to bring it to a professional to have it replaced.  Glue will not help, as the cracks will still exist.

If it is an Apple computer or phone, you can bring it to an Apple Store to have it repaired; however, this can sometimes be a bit pricey.